# iOS StackViews with proportionally filled Subviews and intrinsic width not behaving as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

Following this article I was trying to get proportional sizing on StackViews working.

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/02/07/uistackviev-proportional-custom-uiviews/

The assumption was that by overriding intrinsicContentSize we can specify a new number and it will figure out the ratio of the sizes of subViews and resize the views accordingly.

When I repeat the implementation I am getting some odd behaviour. The ratio is preserved but the last item is stretched to take up the remaining space instead of the items being scaled across the entire width of the parent view (see image below).

Code:

```
class GuageSection: UIView {

    var width: Double = 1.0

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: width, height: 1.0)
    }
}
```

which is used like this

```
var guageWrapper = UIStackView()
guageWrapper.distribution = .fillProportionally

let guageSection = GuageSection()
guageSection.width = category.range // Currently Doubles ranging between 1.0 and 1.5
guageWrapper.addArrangedSubview(guageSection)
```

[image]

I have tried playing with the translateAutoResizingMaskInConstraints property and a few other things but nothing seems to change this behaviour.

If anyone has seen this behaviour before a good point in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @juanlumn, this account doesn't have any privileges.

Comment: have you changed your StackView distribution to Fill Proportionally?

Comment: Yes I have. Just had to double check I wasn't being that silly.

Comment: I have added more detail to the implementation

Comment: What do you mean by "doubles ranging"? Have you tried to remove labels from your custom views? It can be caused by UILabel's intrinsicContentSize.

Comment: I mean that the subviews widths are set using doubles ranging from 1.0 - 1.5 at the moment. 

I have not I will give that a shot.

Comment: I want the contents to fill the entire stack view. I just want it to do that proportional to the width values I give it.

For example subviews with widths of

1, 2 and 1

Should render a stack view that is the width of its superview and with 3 subviews where the first and third take up a quarter of the superviews width and the second takes up half of it. 

See the article linked to above for details about the behaviour I am trying to replicate.

Comment: Oh and to answer your question I did have the stack views edges pined to the superview (vertically and horizontally). Would it be a better idea to constrain the width to the superviews width instead?

Comment: @BrianWilliams - are you laying this out in Storyboard or via code?

Comment: Hi there, I am laying it out in code.

Comment: @BrianWilliams - whoops, yep, that was obvious from your question... I'm adding an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this is a "bug" or not, but... It appears `UIStackView` has an issue with `.fillProportionally` and its initial layout calculations.

If `.spacing` is `0` (zero), `.fillProportionally` seems to work as documented. If `.spacing` is **non-Zero**, we see issues.

So, try this... Initialize your stack view with spacing of `0`, then:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    guageWrapper.spacing = 2
}
```

You'll need a reference to `guageWrapper`, of course, so create it as a class-level var.

---

**Edit:**

I whipped up an example with the stack view as part of a custom `UIView`.

Using an "intrinsic widths" array of `1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5`, here is the result:

[image]

[image]

Everything is done via code (no `@IBOutlets` needed), so you should be able to run this by adding a new view controller and setting its custom class to `GuageTestViewController`:

```
//
//  GuageTestViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 2/28/19.
//

import UIKit

class GuageSection: UIView {

    let label: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let colorView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    var width: Double = 1.0

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: width, height: 1.0)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        self.addSubview(colorView)
        self.addSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            colorView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            colorView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            colorView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            colorView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10.0),

            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorView.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: colorView.bottomAnchor, constant: 2.0),

            ])

    }

}

class GuageView: UIView {

    var pStack = UIStackView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 41.0 / 255.0, green: 59.0 / 255.0, blue: 78.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        pStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pStack.axis = .horizontal
        pStack.alignment = .fill
        pStack.distribution = .fillProportionally
        pStack.spacing = 0
        addSubview(pStack)

        let labels = [
            "Low", "Ideal", "Pre-High", "High", "Very High"
        ]

        let rgbVals = [
            [252, 191, 127],
            [ 79, 197, 140],
            [252, 191, 127],
            [249, 129, 131],
            [217,  92,  98],
            ]

        let widths = [
            1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5
        ]

        for i in 0..<labels.count {
            let v = GuageSection()
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            v.label.text = labels[i]
            v.width = widths[i]
            let rgb = rgbVals[i].compactMap { CGFloat($0) / 255.0 }
            v.colorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: rgb[0], green: rgb[1], blue: rgb[2], alpha: 1.0)
            v.label.textColor = v.colorView.backgroundColor
            pStack.addArrangedSubview(v)
        }

        // constrain the stack view 20-pts from top, leading and trailing, 8-pts from bottom
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            pStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            pStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            pStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            pStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // no height constraint ...
            // let the guageSection view height determine the stack view height
            //      guageSection has 10-pt tall view and multi-line capable label

            ])

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        pStack.spacing = 2

    }
}

class GuageTestViewController: UIViewController {

    var gView = GuageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 31.0 / 255.0, green: 46.0 / 255.0, blue: 61.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        view.addSubview(gView)
        gView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // constrain the view to leading and trailing, and 40-pts from the top
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            gView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            gView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            gView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),

            // no height constraint ...
            // let the GuageView's content determine the height

            ])

    }

}
```

Comment: You absolute legend. Thank you for that it was driving me loopy.

I am glad it is a bug and not just my stupidity. (Hopefully not by designed because that would be daft)

Comment: just so you know this didn't fix it in my case so I am still looking for an explanation of the behaviour so I can fix it. 

As putting the spacing setting either in the initialisation, in the view controller or in the views draw method seems to break it. I will keep poking it to see if I can infer the behaviour. But thought it pertinent to let people know.

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code? Just enough to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @BrianWilliams - I edited my answer to include a simple example where the stack view is part of a custom view class. Seems to handle the `.fillProportionally` quirk without issue.